# JSON to XML converter that handles attributes - javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, json

I have a JSON object that I unfortunately need to convert to XML.  The XML has to be very specific including what parts are attributes and what parts are values.  Is there any JSON to XML javascript tool that will allow one to specify which parts are attributes?

For example, this JSON (ignore any formatting errors in this JSON example as I'm just typing it - assume the actual JSON is correctly formatted):

```
{content: { type: "text", content: "blah blah blah" }}
```

to this XML:

```
<content type="text">blah blah blah</content>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Most of the tools ask some prefix to identify a property as attribute and they remove prefix while parsing the XML. In practical, prefix is not complete property name because it is expected that a tag can have multiple attributes and they can't have same name. Moreover once the prefix is removed while parsing there will be an empty attribute name. So it is a rare case to handle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer seems to be no.  I ended up going through the JSON in a custom function, converting each part to xml strings, concatenating them together, and then running `jQuery.parseXML()` on it.  Maybe not the most elegant, but it got the code into perfect (for my situation) XML.

Answer (score 0):

Json.net would be for serverside conversions

i have alos linked a github project. if it doesnt support your needs out of the box you can massage it to support your conversions

[JSON.net XML- JSON Json - XML](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/ConvertingJSONandXML.htm)

[Github json to xml](https://github.com/SiegfriedEhret/json2xml/blob/master/json2xml.js)